# Hybris Commerce Build failed on initialize on Azure VM

Tags: initialization, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to install a Hybris Commerce 5.7 on an Azure VM (Windows Server 2012, D13 configuration) for testing. The install.bat -r b2c_acc command builds successfull, but on install.bat -r b2c_acc **initialize** I get the following error:

```
     [java] ERROR [main] [DefaultSolrServerService] de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Error while executing Solr start command for instance: [name: default, port:
8983]
     [java] WARN  [main] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
     [java] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spri
ng.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Error while executing Solr start command for instance: [name: defa
ult, port: 8983]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbsttApplicationContext.java:480)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.refreshContext(HybrisContextFactory.java:98)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:176)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:76)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getOrAddUnit(RegionCacheAdapter.java:206)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.get(AbstractCacheUnit.java:180)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.ComposedType_HJMPWrapper$FindByCodeExact1FinderResult.getFinderResult(ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.java:1727)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.ejbFindByCodeExact(ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.java:1786)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.callMethod(Utilities.java:1069)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.callMethod(Utilities.java:1059)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.framework.HomeInvocationHandler.invoke(HomeInvocationHandler.java:93)
     [java]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.findByCodeExact(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.TypeManagerEJB.findByCodeExact(TypeManagerEJB.java:271)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.TypeManagerEJB.getComposedType(TypeManagJB.java:459)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.migration.DeploymentMigrationUtil.migrateSelectedDeployments(DeploymentMigrationUtil.java:458)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.migrateCoreTypes(AbstractTenant.java:910)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:716)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:658)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:639)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:700)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:544)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenantForInit(Registry.java:616)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.ClientExecuter.execute(ClientExecuter.java:36)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.execute(Loader.java:145)
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:121)
```

I added the 8983 port to the VM's endpoints, but that didn't help.

Any idea what causes this error?

Comment: Are you sure `initialize` command should work with gradle recipes? Basically, b2c_acc recipe should initialize and run the Hybris platform with b2c accelerator out-of-the-box. If you want to perform manual initialization, you should go to `platform/bin` directory in commerce suite, make sure you have ant installed and optionally call `ant clean` and then call `ant initialize`. Make sure, you have correctly configured `localextensions.xml` file and all your neccessary extensions are there.

Comment: Is this the full error trace ? Anything else listing on 8983 ? Is your account an administrator account ?

Comment: @piotr.wittchen the command should be fine and the recipe should have created the correct localextensions.xml. To me this sounds a bit like a potential windows specific problem regarding running solr as a service, maybe user rights etc.

Comment: The Windows user is an administrator account. Also the same files and commands work on my local machine. The problem indeed seems to be related to Solr. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Configure a separate Solr server rather using the one bundled with the ECP?

Comment: Found the solution: Using the pre-installed Administrator user the initialize process built fine. Don't know why it wouldn't work with my other account, which is set to admin.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you have something using your port 8983, I would say it's probably another Solr instance. Try accessing

http://localhost:8983/solr

If you're able to access the solr server, that's your problem. You can stop it running this command from hybris/bin/platform:

```
ant stopSolrServer
```

To avoid this happening, whenever you stop your hybris instance you should wait for Solr to finish gracefully instead of trying to kill the process multiple times.

Comment: No, as I wrote above, using the pre-installed by Azure Administrator user the initialize process builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Using the pre-installed by Azure Administrator user the initialize process built fine. Don't know why it wouldn't work with my other account, which is set to admin.